# Djando admin wont log in, no errors

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm making a pretty simple Django app and I cant get the Admin site to behave...

**Symptoms**

- the url `.../admin/` shows me the expected login form
- if I fill in the form incorrectly I get relevant error messages
- if I fill in the form correctly with the details of a superuser (created via manage.py createsuperuser) then the page does not redirect or come up with errors
- using the shell I can successfully authenticate the user I was trying to log in with
- examining the auth_user database table, is_staff, is_avctive, and is_superuser are all set to 1
- if I go to the admin login and attempt to login then the server console output looks fine:

  ```
  [25/Jan/2013 06:27:28] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2028
  [25/Jan/2013 06:27:34] "POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
  [25/Jan/2013 06:27:34] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2028
  ```

**Configuration:**

In my settings file I have:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.admin', ...

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
```

I haven't changed from the default authentication backend

In my url config I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
.......
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

I'm running django 1.3.1 and Python 2.7

**Question:**

How can I fix this? What am I missing?

Comment: My first guess would be cookies. Check if your browser sends cookies correctly. And that they persists between requests (e.g. you don't have settings to store cookies in phony cache).

Comment: does it work in other browsers?

Comment: @alexvasi: My cookie settings look fine to me and have never given me issues on other sites

Comment: @Marat: I've tried Firefox and Chromium... both do the same thing

Comment: is there anything unusual at development server output? Can you check the DB queries (you can get them by using django-debug-toolbar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE was set to True.

Thanks all for your comments